# Reddit oAuth with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, reddit

I can't seem to be able to get the access token from reddit. This is my code by I keep getting a `[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token. Origin http://127.0.0.1:9000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (oauth, line 0)`

Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
var clientId = '############';
var cliendSecret = '##################';
var redirectUri = encodeURI('http://127.0.0.1:9000/oauth');
var grantType = 'authorization_code';

var getAccessToken = function (code) {
  var url = 'https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token';

  var attrs = {
    'grant_type': grantType,
    'code': code,
    'redirect_uri': redirectUri
  };

  var encodedAuthHeader = 'Basic ' + btoa(clientId + ':' + cliendSecret);
  var promise = $http(
    {
      url: url,
      method: 'POST',
      data: attrs,
      headers: {'Authorization': encodedAuthHeader}
    }).then(function(response) {
      return response;
    }, function(response) {
      return response;
    });

  return promise;
};
```

I am able to get the access token using the postman plug-in on chrome, so I examined the request from postman and angular and they were vastly different (POST vs. OPTIONS). Any idea how I can create a similar request with Angular? I know that angular is making a CORS request first. Is this something that the reddit server doesn't support?

Thanks!

**Postman**:

```
  POST /api/v1/access_token HTTP/1.1
  Host: ssl.reddit.com
  Connection: keep-alive
  Content-Length: 403
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
  Origin: chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
  Authorization: Basic Vmd2dUNXT3RCb214d3c6YWh5d21kVXd4czJEXzhScThaNEhSU3ZzMG1F
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarytxCWa5t6OHsTtEU0
  Accept: */*
  Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
  Cookie: reddit_session=8647320%2C2014-02-05T14%3A38%3A09%2C668f4a063ccd2b118a7504c9849d9f0ec4595444
```

**Angular**:

```
  OPTIONS /api/v1/access_token HTTP/1.1
  Host: ssl.reddit.com
  Connection: keep-alive
  Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
  Origin: http://127.0.0.1:9000
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
  Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization, content-type
  Accept: */*
  Referer: http://127.0.0.1:9000/oauth?state=test&code=40V-fHS-4r8COQgKUP08Q8dgzkk
  Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Comment: To check if it's really just a CORS issue, you can temporarily disable the check by chrome as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: @PieterHerroelen any idea how I can fix this without disabling security mode? How can I get angular to ignore the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

Comment: @nknj Did you implement oauth successfully?  Are you using a chrome extension?  I'm trying to do something similar and would love to see some code if you have a working example.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at my answer on this question for some background on CORS: [Angular force disable CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931964/angular-force-disable-cors/22932780#22932780)

In your case I think you should set the `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data`.

For all requests:

```
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
```

For just one request:

```
 $http.post(url,data, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
```